How to copy a selected range of cells in VBA?
I am relatively new to VBA. I have successfully selected the top 20 rows of a worksheet after I have applied a filter to the worksheet. I am now trying to take these top 20 rows and move them to a new worksheet, but I keep getting errors.
Here is the code that I have:
Sub TwentyRows()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngF As Range
    Dim rng20 As Range

    Set rngF = Range("A16:H520").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    For Each rng In Range("A16:H520")
        If Not Intersect(rng, rngF) Is Nothing Then
            If rng20 Is Nothing Then
                Set rng20 = rng
            Else
                Set rng20 = Union(rng20, rng)
            End If
            If rng20.Cells.Count = 140 Then Exit For
        End If
    Next rng
    Debug.Print rng20.Address
    rng20.Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

The final two lines are where the issue arises as it is written now it says "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed." Again, I am just trying to take that selection made by rng10.Select and copy it to a new worksheet.
The significance of the number 140 is that I have 7 columns and I want 20 rows so 7x20 =140 cells. The filter I am trying to implement is a worksheet by worksheet filter:
'Updateby Normal
   Dim xWs As Worksheet
   On Error Resume Next
   For Each xWs In Worksheets
      xWs.Range("E15").AutoFilter 5, ">0.002"
   Next
End Sub```



rng10.Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")?

rng10.Select is a line of code that selects the range rng10 i.e. you cannot put an equal sign to the left or to the right of it and you cannot use it as a parameter. BTW, you don't need to select anything as illustrated in BigBen's previous comment. Also, you don't need to unionize the range because all cells of rngF are surely cells of rng10 i.e. rngF and rng10 are the same ranges. What is the significance of the number 140? Try to explain more accurately what it is you are trying to do here.

I listed this as a duplicate due to using a non-contiguous range and copy paste with rng10.Copy Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1) gives RTE 1004:  This action won't work on multiple selections.  I had originally written what Ben commented, but deleted my comment recognizing it does not work even for a simple Set rng = Union(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 2)).  The answers in the linked post provide alternatives to allow for a more robust solution.

Debug.Print twenty_rows might help you see the problem.

rng10 ?  not rng20 ? Add Option Explicit at top.

Copy Top N Filtered Rows



Main
Sub FilterAcross()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_TOP_LEFT_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A15"
    Const CRITERIA_COLUMN As String = "E" ' worksheet column
    Const CRITERIA_STRING As String = ">0.002"
    Const TOP_ROWS_COUNT As Long = 2
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet2"
    Const DST_TOP_LEFT_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A1"
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the first destination cell.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = dws.Range(DST_TOP_LEFT_CELL_ADDRESS)
    
    ' Clear existing destination data.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dcell.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - dcell.Row + 1, _
        dws.Columns.Count - dcell.Column + 1)
    drg.Clear
        
    ' Calculate the range column.
    Dim CriteriaColumn As Long: CriteriaColumn = GetRangeColumn( _
        dws.Range(SRC_TOP_LEFT_CELL_ADDRESS), CRITERIA_COLUMN)
    If CriteriaColumn = 0 Then Exit Sub
         
    Dim CopyHeaders As Boolean: CopyHeaders = True
    Dim TopRowsCount As Long: TopRowsCount = TOP_ROWS_COUNT + 1 ' headers
         
    Dim sws As Worksheet, srg As Range, scell As Range, dlcell As Range
    Dim sfrg As Range, sftrg As Range
    
    For Each sws In wb.Worksheets
        If sws.Name <> DST_SHEET_NAME Then
            Set srg = RefCurrentRegion(sws.Range(SRC_TOP_LEFT_CELL_ADDRESS))
            If srg.Rows.Count > 1 Then ' header + at least one row
                ' Reference the filtered rows.
                Set sfrg = Nothing
                Set sfrg = RefAutoFilteredRows(srg, CriteriaColumn, _
                    CRITERIA_STRING, dcell, CopyHeaders)
                ' Reference the top filtered rows and copy.
                If Not sfrg Is Nothing Then
                    Set sftrg = RefTopRows(sfrg, TopRowsCount)
                    sftrg.Copy dcell
                End If
                ' Reference the destination cell.
                Set dlcell = drg.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
                If CopyHeaders Then
                    CopyHeaders = dlcell Is Nothing
                    If Not CopyHeaders Then TopRowsCount = TOP_ROWS_COUNT
                End If
                If Not CopyHeaders Then
                    Set dcell = dws.Cells(dlcell.Row + 1, dcell.Column)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next sws
    
    MsgBox "Created a list of top " & TOP_ROWS_COUNT _
        & " rows per worksheet" & vbLf & "meeting the criteria """ _
        & CRITERIA_STRING & """ in column """ & CRITERIA_COLUMN & """.", _
        vbInformation
    
End Sub

Help
Function GetRangeColumn( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    ByVal WorksheetColumn As Variant) _
As Long
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    Dim wsColumn As Long
    On Error Resume Next
        wsColumn = rg.Worksheet.Columns(WorksheetColumn).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wsColumn < 1 Then Exit Function
    GetRangeColumn = wsColumn - rg.Column + 1
End Function
     

Function RefCurrentRegion(topLeftCell As Range) As Range
    If topLeftCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    With topLeftCell.Cells(1).CurrentRegion
        Set RefCurrentRegion = topLeftCell.Resize( _
            .Row + .Rows.Count - topLeftCell.Row, _
            .Column + .Columns.Count - topLeftCell.Column)
    End With
End Function

Function RefAutoFilteredRows( _
    ByVal srg As Range, _
    ByVal CriteriaColumn As String, _
    ByVal CriteriaString As String, _
    ByVal dcell As Range, _
    ByVal CopyHeaders As Boolean) _
As Range
        
    If CriteriaColumn > srg.Columns.Count Then Exit Function
    
    ' Clear existing filters.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = srg.Worksheet
    If sws.FilterMode Then sws.ShowAllData
    
    ' Store the auto filter mode state in a variable.
    Dim WasSheetAutoFiltered As Boolean:
    WasSheetAutoFiltered = sws.AutoFilterMode
    
    ' Turn off auto filtering because the wrong data could be auto-filtered.
    sws.AutoFilterMode = False
        
    ' Filter the range.
    srg.AutoFilter CriteriaColumn, CriteriaString
        
    ' Reference the filtered rows.
    If CopyHeaders Then ' including the headers
        Set RefAutoFilteredRows = srg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Else ' excluding the headers
        With srg.Resize(srg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
            On Error Resume Next
                Set RefAutoFilteredRows = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
    End If
    
    ' Restore the auto filter mode state.
    If WasSheetAutoFiltered Then sws.ShowAllData Else sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
End Function

Function RefTopRows( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    ByVal TopRowsCount As Long, _
    Optional ByVal IgnoreFewerRows As Boolean = False) _
As Range
    
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function ' i.e. 'RefTopRows Is Nothing'
    If TopRowsCount < 1 Then Exit Function ' i.e. 'RefTopRows Is Nothing'
    
    Dim TopRow As Long: TopRow = rg.Row
    
    Dim arg As Range, rrg As Range
    Dim CurrentRow As Long, BottomRow As Long, RowsCount As Long
    
    For Each arg In rg.Areas
        For Each rrg In arg.Rows
            CurrentRow = rrg.Row
            If CurrentRow > BottomRow Then
                BottomRow = CurrentRow
                RowsCount = RowsCount + 1
            End If
            If RowsCount = TopRowsCount Then
                Set RefTopRows = Intersect(rg, _
                    rg.Worksheet.Rows(TopRow).Resize(BottomRow - TopRow + 1))
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next rrg
    Next arg

    If IgnoreFewerRows Then Exit Function ' i.e. 'RefTopRows Is Nothing'
    
    Set RefTopRows = rg

End Function


Initial Post (Not Enough Information)
Copy Filtered Rows

Here's a common scenario. Consider it as a blueprint since you need to share more information to get a more accurate answer.
Play with it in a copy of your workbook and see where it gets you. If you get stuck, ask another question.
Usually, you reference the source range, filter it and perform the various operations with the filtered rows in the same sub so take it all with a grain of salt.

Sub CopyFilteredRows()

    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' If it isn't, use 'ActiveWorkbook' instead, or better specify with e.g.
    ' 'Set wb = Workbooks("MyWorkbook.xlsx")'.
    
    ' Reference the source and destination worksheets.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.ActiveSheet ' improve e.g. like 'dws'!
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
        
    ' Reference the whole source range.
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A16:H520")
    ' Dynamically, something like (a bit inaccurate):
'    If sws.FilterMode Then
'        Set srg = sws.AutoFilter.Range
'    Else
'        Exit Sub ' not filtered
'    End If
        
    ' Reference the filtered rows (including the headers).
    Dim sfrg As Range: Set sfrg = srg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    ' I usually slip in something like this to clear the filter:
    'sws.ShowAllData
    
    ' Uncomment the operation you wish to perform.
    
    ' Copy all columns.
    Debug.Print sfrg.Address(0, 0) ' max 255 characters limit
    'sfrg.Copy Destination:=dws.Range("A1")
    
    ' Copy a specific column.
    Dim sfcrg As Range: Set sfcrg = Intersect(sfrg, sws.Columns("F"))
    Debug.Print sfcrg.Address(0, 0) ' max 255 characters limit
    'sfcrg.Copy Destination:=dws.Range("A1")
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Filtered rows copied.", vbInformation
    
End Sub


This is the filter I am using:
'Updateby Normal
   Dim xWs As Worksheet
   On Error Resume Next
   For Each xWs In Worksheets
      xWs.Range("E15").AutoFilter 5, ">0.002"
   Next
End Sub```

Ideally, I want the filter to be applied to all sheets (which it is), then select the 20 top rows (using the sub I posted here), then all rows from the different sheets copy and pasted to 'Sheet2.' I am doing it piece by piece just because it is easier for me to follow as I am not a VBA expert, but plan on combining at the end.

Your code block was successful in copying all the rows from my active sheet to a new sheet and I assume that is because I have the filter and selection criteria in a separate sub. I will work on combining all of them into one!

You're looping through all worksheets which could mean that there are 2 workbooks, one with the worksheets and another with Sheet2. Which one has the code and what is the name of the other one (e.g. Test.xlsx or should it be the active workbook)? If the previous is not true, shouldn't the loop skip Sheet2? Please clarify.

Also, columns A:H is 8 columns. Which 7 ones do you need to copy? Or is it 8?

Column B is hidden so skipping that one. The code works just fine for the selection. If I switch where I have rng20.select to rng20.Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1"), it copies the first 20 rows to Sheet2 but then after that I get a this action can't run on multiple selections error. This is all one workbook and I am still at beginning stages, just trying to get the functionality down.
